# JavaScript syntax clarifying

Tags: javascript

For the following syntax

```
    a = {
    get p() {
        alert(1)
    }
};
alert(a.p);
```

It prompts me `1`, than `undefined`.
For

```
a = {
    set p(x) {
        alert(x)
    }
};
alert(a.p);
```

It prompts me undefined.

I do not totally understand the behaviour,
what does

```
a = {
    get p() {
        alert(1)
    }
}

and

a = {
    set p(x) {
        alert(x)
    }
};
```

mean?

Comment: The method `p` does not return any value, thats why the second alerts give you undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of object properties: `data` properties and `accessor` properties.
 Accessor properties are accessed by `getters` and `setters`.
Your object `a` is intended as object with accessor property which called `p`.
Normally, such objects are declared in the following way:

```
a = {
    _p: 'my value', // intended as private
    get p() {
        return this._p;
    },
    set p(x) {
        this._p = x;
    }  
};

console.log(a.p);  // gives 'my value'
a.p = 'new value'; 
console.log(a.p);  // gives 'new value'
```

Another way is to use `Object.defineProperty()` method which lets you to set all needed properties attributes. Like this:

```
var a = {p: 'my value'};
    Object.defineProperty(a, 'p', {
      get: function() { return this.p; },
      set: function(newValue) { this.p = newValue; },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

because `p()` method returns nothing hence it returns `undefined`

if you do

```
a={get p(){alert(1); return 2;}};
alert(a.p);
```

it will alert `1` and then `2` since this `p()` method returned `2`

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] - You changed your original question so this answer doesn't cover everything.

`p` is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function - It is called whenever you access the `p` property.  In your `getter` you have `alert(1)`.

The `getter` function doesn't return anything.  Thus, `p` is `undefined`.  So the `alert(a.p)` alerts `undefined`.

Thus, your program does:

- Get value of `a.p`: `alert(a.p)`
- Calls `p` getter function. Which has `alert(1)`
- `p` getter function returns nothing
- Thus `alert(a.p)` alerts `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
{get p(){alert(1)}}
```

this is an object that has a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) `p`

when you use `a.p` it will use that getter to retrieve some value

so when you do `alert(a.p);` it first call the getter, so alert `1`, then alert the returned value `undefined`.